# The working of constructor of priority queue

Tags: c++, constructor, priority-queue, std

Can anyone please elaborate how the objects are compared before insertion in the priority queue for following code. Also what is significance of p(comp) in the constructor of priority queue..
code--

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct trainer
{  int a, int b;  }

bool comp(trainer x,trainer y)
{  return x.a>y.a;  }

int main(void)
{
  priority_queue<trainer, vector<trainer>, function<bool(trainer,trainer)> > p(comp);
  trainer x1,x2,x3;
  x1.a=2;x1.b=3;
  x2.a=9;x2.b=1;
  x3.a=21;x3.b=22;
  p.push(x2);p.push(x1);p.push(x3);
}
```

Comment: `comp` is the function used to compare two objects of the `trainer` struct

Answer (score 0):

A priority queue is ordered. By default it uses `std::less` to order the elements and the largest element is at the first position (top). You can pass a different compare function to change the order, e.g. `std::greater` to have the smallest element at the first position. In your example the function `comp` is passed to the constructor of the priority queue:

```
p(comp)
```

Whenever you insert an element, it is compared using `comp` in logarithmic time complexity with other elements and placed in the correct position.

You can read [std::priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) for more information.